# How can object files with different optimization level be linked together in C/C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, linker

Using the web site Compiler Exlplorer, I noticed that GCC, without optimization, uses the stack to pass the arguments to a function.

Enabling the optimization, if there are few parameters, GCC uses the micropocessor registers to pass the parameters because it is faster.

If some tranlation units are compiled without optimization and others with, how can the linker join them together and let an optimized funcion call a not-optimized one (or vice versa) without messing up all the parameters exchanged?

Comment: there's a standard contract for the binary interface

Comment: Your claim about the different behavior with and without optimizations shouldn't be true. Can you link to an example where you see that behavior?

Comment: Was the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) [explicitly] changed somehow..? Doing such definitely breaks ABI.

Comment: Calling conventions (how arguments are passed to a function, and return values passed back) are generally specified as part of the ABI (Application Binary Interface).   Optimisation settings, however, typically do not change the ABI - so (among other things) do not introduce incompatibility when linking.   Other compilation settings may affect ABI, so those settings need to be the same across a program to avoid incompatibilities.  Those settings are generally not related to optimisation (and more typically reduce or compromise benefits achieved by code optimisation).

Answer (score 4):

> How can object files with different optimization level be linked together in C/C++?

Language implementations follow a "calling convention" (or several) which is a scheme for how subroutines receive parameters from their caller and how they return a result ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention)). More generally, calling convention is part of the "application binary interface" ([ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)) of the compilation unit.

As long as the translation units use the same ABI, they can be linked and can call each other.

> If some tranlation units are compiled without optimization and others with, how can the linker join them together

Typically, linkers assume that translation units have matching ABI and aren't able to rectify a mismatch.

Some compiler options can change the ABI of the compilation unit. Such options must match across all linked units.

Ideally, compiler options that are categorised as "optimisation" should not affect the ABI. As long as they don't affect ABI, they can differ between translation units. You have to consult the documentation of the compiler to find out which options affect ABI.